# Is the load( ) method in the audio element re-downloading the audio?

Tags: javascript, audio, methods, load, element

I'm making an audio heavy webpage. I've read that there are some issues with audio playback on certain systems that are solved by calling the load() method before the play() method, so I'm designing everything around that premise.

I'm clueless about the audio element, and I'm worried that the load() method is rising the bandwith consumption. This is what I'm doing:

```
var x = new Audio("x.mp3");

function playMe(){
    x.load();
    x.play();   
}
```

It's my understanding that the audio file is downloaded when the x Audio object is created. My concern is if the load() method is downloading it again every time the play button is clicked.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check your browser inspect tools - do you notice any new http request on further `x.load()` call?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just starting in programming and I have no idea of what you are talking about. Where can I find the browser inspect tools? Thanks for your time and reply.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview - check Network tab then!

Comment: Thanks. According to the network tab there is a new request on every x.load()call. If I remove the load() method from the playMe function there are no requests for every function call. What does this mean?

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your time and help. Could you mind to answer this question? Seems that I can't self-answer until my account is 8 hours old.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your source for *"some issues with audio playback on certain systems that are solved by calling the load() method before the play() method"*?

Comment: I can't find the page! It was an article on the Audio element, and the issue was that iOS didn't play the sound when play() was called. The article also referenced a "burried" thread in stackoverflow that suggested calling the load() method before the play() solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your own if the `x.load()` method re-downloads the file:

1. open your browser developer tools [e.g. [in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview)];
2. check the Network tab for activity on `x.load()` calls.